# This is NOT a riddle puzzle

Tags: riddle, steganography

> Riddle me this:
>
> I am not a riddle.
>   Although I may look like one, I am not.
>   I am hearing you call me a riddle, so...
>   Since riddles can't hear, I mustn't be one!
>   I assure you, I am not a riddle.
>
> Can you believe that I'm not a riddle?
>   And can you believe that I'm telling the truth?
>   Now, I am more unusual than a riddle.
>   The truth here is that I am literally 'I', just me...
>   Oh, nevermind. *I can't organise my thoughts*, I'm not particularly interested in this riddle - I mean not a riddle!

Really, it's not a riddle. But I'm going to ask it anyway:

What am I? I won't always be this, so perhaps a better question is:
What am I right now?

(EDIT for clarification: the answer will use information from EVERY line in the riddle)

Comment: Does this need the [tag:wordplay] tag?

Comment: Possibly not. As with my not a number sequence puzzle, I find it difficult to find any suitable tag apart from the tag that it is not.

Comment: Are you going to post something titled 'This is NOT a puzzle' anytime soon? :P

Comment: If I could without getting it flagged for irrelevance, I think that idea would be good fun :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> Rather bored.

Explanation:

> The first letters in each line of the second verse, along with the first letter of the first line after the yellow box, read out CANTOR. This gives away that we need to read the diagonal. If you take the $n$th letter of the $n$th line in every line inside the yellow box, this is what you get.

Comment: The same hint is in the italics. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Answer 1

I think the answer must be

> a shapeshifter

### Answer 2

*Based on the 1st revision of the question*

Maybe, the answer is:

> a paradox

Quoting Wikipedia:

> A paradox [...] leads to a self-contradictory or a logically
>  unacceptable conclusion. [It] involves contradictory yet
>  interrelated elements [...]

Comment: Cool guess! I added a new quick edit, so as to make clear my design ideals and what I was going for with this puzzle.

Comment: It will be a word or a phrase which answers 'What am I right now?' Other than the solution path to the answer, there are hints scattered throughout the puzzle which will confirm the answer as correct.

Comment: Is my second attempt right?

Comment: Your first riddle was really nice :) Sorry about the edits to this puzzle, I thought I should've made some things clearer - so however cool the guess 'shapeshifter' is, it's not the intended answer and doesn't make use of information in every line.

Comment: Thanks. Was it better than one you recently answered (incorrectly, though)? The GOD one, I mean.

Comment: I can't really make a judgement until I solve/someone solves the god puzzle :) Certainly the compress riddle provided more information, which is always nice, but I'm reserving an opinion on the god riddle until it's over.

Comment: Can you access [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52180/discussion-between-thegreatescaper-and-soha-farhin-pine)? It's usually easier to have longer conversations there.